# Understanding disassembly information from Visual Studio's dumpbin and GNU's objdump

Tags: disassembly, windows, assembly, objdump

I usually write my code on Windows, and there are two different types of development environments, each providing their own tools to view the assembly code of an object file(`*.obj`) or executable (`*.exe`).

If I am working with Visual Studio build system from command line, the `dumpbin /disasm file.obj` command can generate disassemble a binary file. A snippet of a disassembly from an executable, produced by `dumpbin` :

```
  000000014000E712: 41 81 F0 6E 74 65  xor         r8d,6C65746Eh
                    6C
  000000014000E719: 41 81 F1 47 65 6E  xor         r9d,756E6547h
                    75
  000000014000E720: 44 8B D2           mov         r10d,edx
  000000014000E723: 8B F0              mov         esi,eax
  000000014000E725: 33 C9              xor         ecx,ecx
  000000014000E727: 41 8D 43 01        lea         eax,[r11+1]
  000000014000E72B: 45 0B C8           or          r9d,r8d
  000000014000E72E: 0F A2              cpuid
  000000014000E730: 41 81 F2 69 6E 65  xor         r10d,49656E69h
                    49
  000000014000E737: 89 04 24           mov         dword ptr [rsp],eax
```

However, if I am working with the GNU toolkit (I mean mingw64, which works with native windows binaries), then running `objdump -D file.obj` gives a disassembly like this:

```
   14000e712:   41 81 f0 6e 74 65 6c    xor    $0x6c65746e,%r8d
   14000e719:   41 81 f1 47 65 6e 75    xor    $0x756e6547,%r9d
   14000e720:   44 8b d2                mov    %edx,%r10d
   14000e723:   8b f0                   mov    %eax,%esi
   14000e725:   33 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
   14000e727:   41 8d 43 01             lea    0x1(%r11),%eax
   14000e72b:   45 0b c8                or     %r8d,%r9d
   14000e72e:   0f a2                   cpuid  
   14000e730:   41 81 f2 69 6e 65 49    xor    $0x49656e69,%r10d
   14000e737:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%rsp)
```

Now, it is immediately clear that both are providing the same information. However, I want to know what the numbers on the left column mean (e.g. `14000e712`)? Also why is the instruction written differently (e.g. on the first line, `dumpbin` writes `r8d,6C65746Eh`, while `objdump` writes `$0x6c65746e,%r8d`). Why is this, and what do the different representations mean? Additionally dumpbin seems to write extra information such as `dword ptr` that `objdump` doesn't write.

Comment: `dumpbin` is using what is known as Intel (dis)assembly syntax. `By default, objdump`, being a GNU utility is using what is known as AT&T (dis)assembly syntax. If you want `objdump` to display output in Intel syntax, add `-Mintel` to your `objdump` command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down. The first and most obvious difference is Intel syntax (`dumpbin`) vs. AT&T syntax (`objdump`) for the output you give. That's be the part of your question:

> Also why is the instruction written differently (e.g. on the first line, dumpbin writes `r8d,6C65746Eh`, while objdump writes `$0x6c65746e,%r8d`). Why is this, and what do the different representations mean?

However, `objdump` lets you choose between the two and just defaults to AT&T (aka `att`). Excerpt from the `man` page:

```
"intel"
"att"
    Select between intel syntax mode and AT&T syntax mode.
```

So you could simply use: `objdump -D -M intel ...` (also `-Mintel`) to get way closer to the output from `dumpbin`.

However, a comparison of the syntax variants can be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax). [This dated overview](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/brennan/brennan_att_inline_djgpp.html) may also help. The most important difference is that Intel syntax places the target first and the source last, whereas with AT&T it's the opposite.

Let's take the instruction you gave:

- Intel: `xor r8d,6C65746Eh`

  - `xor` instruction
  - (first) target operand is `r8d` (lower 32-bit of the `r8` register)
  - (second) source operand is a literal `6C65746Eh` (the hexadecimal is denoted via the trailing `h` here)
- AT&T: `xor $0x6c65746e,%r8d`

  - `xor` instruction
  - (first) source operand is a literal `$0x6c65746e` (the hexadecimal is denoted via the leading `0x` here, IIRC `$` is for literals/addresses)
  - (second) target operand is `%r8d` (lower 32-bit of the `r8` register)

NB: This is largely a matter of taste. Binutils (the set of tools around `objdump`) and others like GDB default to AT&T syntax, but you can tell them to use the Intel syntax. Most of the disassembly I work with is Intel syntax, but it's good to be aware of the two syntax variants and know how they compare.

> However, I want to know what the numbers on the left column mean (e.g. 14000e712)?

Those are the addresses. You probably know that executables typically take a different form when mapped into memory than on disk and that address implies two things:

1. it pretends that the image is mapped at base address 0x140000000
2. 0x14000e712 is simply an address with offset 0xe712 *into* the mapped image

Edit 1: Oh and perhaps one word about this `mov dword ptr [rsp],eax` versus `mov %eax,(%rsp)` business. I find the Intel syntax more readable, since it doesn't make be think where the syntax can give the clue. "Write DWORD to address pointed to by `rsp`, fair enough". However, I suppose the reasoning behind the more concise AT&T syntax is that the knowledge about the operation's size (DWORD) can be deduced from the operand (`eax`) and so it simply leaves out the more or less cosmetic hint of `dword ptr`.